# Add a filter Filter to SQL Query based on geometry generated on-the-fly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, geometry

I am creating a LINESTRING geometry type that is based on two point's geometries. To get the two different points, I am joining on a to and from id field.

I have an sql query like this:

```
SELECT geometry::STGeomFromText(
CONCAT('LINESTRING(',
(SELECT CONCAT(fstruc.Shape.STX, ' ', fstruc.Shape.STY)),
',', 
(SELECT CONCAT(tstruc.Shape.STX, ' ', tstruc.Shape.STY)),
')')
, 103772) geom, 

FROM dbo.SAN_TELEVISE vid

JOIN dbo.san_struc fstruc
ON fstruc.cid = vid.f_struc_cid

JOIN dbo.san_struc tstruc 
ON tstruc.cid = vid.t_struc_cid

WHERE fstruc.cid IS NOT NULL 
AND tstruc.cid IS NOT NULL
-- THIS DOESN'T WORK: AND geom.STIsValid() = 1
```

The query works, I am getting a pretty good result, but there are some bad data rows here though, and ArcMap is choking on some line strings that only have one point. So I want to apply a filter to the query to eliminate these bad rows before ArcMap gets them.

Something like `geom.STIsValid ( )  = 1` would do it, but I can't get my sql query to run if I add this to the where clause. I get the error: 
Cannot find either column "geom" or the user-defined function or aggregate "geom.STIsValid", or the name is ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

Found an alternative solution. It uses `.MakeValid()` at the end of the geometry type to fix invalid geometries.

```
SELECT vid.*, geometry::STGeomFromText(
CONCAT('LINESTRING(',
(SELECT CONCAT(fstruc.Shape.STX, ' ', fstruc.Shape.STY)),
',', 
(SELECT CONCAT(tstruc.Shape.STX, ' ', tstruc.Shape.STY)),
')')
, 103772).MakeValid() geom, 
(SELECT cid
FROM dbo.san_pipe 
WHERE vid.f_struc_cid = from_id 
AND vid.t_struc_cid = to_id) found_pipe_id

FROM dbo.SAN_TELEVISE vid
JOIN dbo.san_struc fstruc
ON fstruc.cid = vid.f_struc_cid

JOIN dbo.san_struc tstruc 
ON tstruc.cid = vid.t_struc_cid

WHERE fstruc.cid IS NOT NULL 
AND tstruc.cid IS NOT NULL
```